# Missing DLC in Crimewave edition?

Tags: ps4, payday-2

I have recently started to play Payday 2: Crimewave edition on PS4, and as usual for me, looked at the wiki to get a idea of what playtype exist, what interested me, and which weapon/skill to get for that playtype.

Wanting to go stealth, I wanted to get the Valkyria, but while searching for it s price in the menu, it just weren t there.

Instigating a bit, it also seems that skins, longbow, crossbow, alternative throwable weapon aren t present in the PS4 version.

Did I miss something? Or is there just a "lag" between new content release on PC and PS4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the console versions of Payday 2 lag *way* behind PC, when it comes to content. Also, Overkill Software doesn't exactly have a stellar track record when it comes to releasing the content for consoles at all, altough we've yet to see if this still holds true for the current generation.

There's a full list of DLC availability for different consoles here: http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Downloadable_content_%28Payday_2%29

The [Valkyria](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Valkyria) you mentioned is a [Sokol Character Pack](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Sokol_Character_Pack) -item. As you can see, that's not releases to *any* console version of the game.

Comment: So they are almost one year late in dlc release on console? Wow...

Comment: Only one year? That's better than I thought. All the DLC really isn't a good thing though, just adds more and more cheesy garbage to the game. I used to play quite a bit on PC but I don't play anymore since I got tired of a new DLC every other week.